# How to remove duplicates on specific columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table like this:

```
// users
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id |   name   |  age  | some other cols ..  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ali      | 15    | ..                  |
| 2  | John     | 15    | ..                  |
| 3  | Ali      | 22    | ..                  |
| 4  | Martin   | 18    | ..                  |
| 5  | Ali      | 15    | ..                  |
| 6  | John     | 30    | ..                  |
| 7  | John     | 15    | ..                  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I want to add a **composite** unique index on `name, age` columns. Currently, it gives me `there are duplicates rows` error. Already, I was using `INSERT IGNORE ..` to do this job but sadly `IGNORE` is no longer supported in MySQL.

Anyway, any idea how can I remove rows that have the same values on both `name` and `age` columns **and keep just one of them (one of rows)**? In other words, I want to remove all rows that have the same value on `name` and `age` columns except one of them.

So, here is **the expected result:**

```
// users
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id |   name   |  age  | some other cols ..  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ali      | 15    | ..                  |
| 2  | John     | 15    | ..                  |
| 3  | Ali      | 22    | ..                  |
| 4  | Martin   | 18    | ..                  |
| 6  | John     | 30    | ..                  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: 'IGNORE is no longer supported in MySQL.' - news to me what version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest writing the code as:

```
delete u
    from users u join
         (select u2.name, u2.age, min(u2.id) as min_id
          from users u2
          group by u2.name, u2.age
          having count(*) > 1
         ) u2
         on u.name = u2.name and u.age = u2.age and u2.id > u.min_id;
```

The use of `inner join` with `>` is quite clever.  However, I think that it might attempt to update the same row multiple times.

Consider this example:

```
id    name     age
 1    Doug      42
 2    Doug      42
 3    Doug      42
 4    Doug      42
 5    Doug      42
```

The inner join logic would attempt to delete row "5" four times.  This version only deletes it once.

Comment: `. . . and u2.min_id > u.id;`

Comment: For me the ID check was correct as follows:
`u.uid > u2.min_id`

Answer (score 3):

Hope this works for you:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM users t1 
INNER JOIN users t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.age=t2.age;
```

Comment: In this query, will one row remain (from the ones that have duplicate)?

Comment: @MartinAJ Yes, because of the first condition `t1.id > t2.id`. You can still create a clone of existing data just to be safe

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to *view* your data this way, then a basic select can do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, age, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name, age
) t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name AND t2.age = t1.age AND t2.min_id = t1.id
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

In the case of two or more records which are "duplicate" with respect to having the same name and age values, the above query arbitrarily retains only the record having the smallest `id` value among them.

Answer (score 0):

i created an example for your question:

```
 CREATE TABLE #myList (
  id int,
  [name] VARCHAR(100),
  age  int
);
  --drop table #myList

INSERT INTO #myList
  (id, [name], age  )
VALUES
  (1,'Ali',15),
  (2,'John',15),
  (3,'Ali',22),
  (4,'Martin',18),
  (5,'Ali',15),
  (6,'John',30),
  (7,'John',15)
  
 select id,[name],age from  ( SELECT 
     i.id,
    i.[name] [name],
    i.age age,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.[name] ORDER BY i.id DESC) AS Rank1,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.age ORDER BY i.id DESC) AS Rank2
FROM #myList AS i 

) select1 where  select1.Rank1 =1 or select1.Rank2 =1
```

result =

```
id  name    age
7   John    15
5   Ali     15
4   Martin  18
3   Ali     22
6   John    30
```